How to Implement Pagination with Next and Previous Buttons in Tableau Dashboard?
I'm working on a Tableau dashboard and would like to implement pagination for a large dataset. The goal is to display a maximum of 25 records per page and allow users to navigate between pages using "Next" and "Previous" buttons. Here's what I've done so far:
What I've Implemented:
I created a calculated field to assign a page number to each record using:
'''
INT((INDEX() - 1) / 25) + 1
'''
I created a parameter called Page Number that allows users to select which page they want to view.
I also added a filter to only display records for the selected page:
'''
[Page Number] = [Selected Page Number]
'''
What I Need Help With:
I want to add "Next" and "Previous" buttons to the dashboard that users can click to change the value of the Page Number parameter, moving between pages of records. I'm not sure how to:
Create these buttons in Tableau.
Use actions or calculated fields to dynamically increase or decrease the Page Number when users click "Next" or "Previous."
How can I create buttons that control the parameter value and, by extension, paginate through the records?
The dataset is large, and I need to limit the view to 25 records per page.
I want users to be able to click through the pages without manually typing the page number.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Have you tried these instructions? https://www.phdata.io/blog/how-to-paginate-in-tableau/
